# Refactor code to reduce retardancy by reducing number of code lines

Tags: c#, refactoring

```
 private bool IsValidPhoneAnnuitent(List<PhoneAnnuitant> annuitant)
    {
        if (annuitant is not null && annuitant.Count() > 0 && annuitant[0].Person is not null) return true;
        return false;
    }
    private bool IsValidAddressAnnuitent(List<AddressAnnuitant>? annuitant)
    {
        if (annuitant is not null && annuitant.Count() > 0 && annuitant[0].Person is not null) return true;
        return false;
    }
    private bool IsValidAnnuitent(List<Annuitant>? annuitant)
    {
        if (annuitant is not null && annuitant.Count() > 0 && annuitant[0].Person is not null) return true;
        return false;
    }
    private bool IsValidPhoneInsured(List<PhoneInsured>? insured)
    {
        if (insured is not null && insured.Count() > 0 && insured[0].Person is not null) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

[image]

Is there any possibility of merging all these method into a single method  to reduce retardant code and to achieve code readability. Could any one please suggest me any alternative code .

Comment: I could imagine this as an ExtensionMethod on `List<T>`. But then I'd not use `Count()` but `Count`. Do thoese classes share an Interface by which we could know they have a `Person` property?

Comment: Why are you checking only first element of a sequence (eg `insured[0].Person is not null`)? That doesn't make much sense for me tbh.

Answer (score 3):

I could see this as an extension method:

```
// Assuming there is something like 
interface IHasPerson
{
    PersonType? Person {get;}
}

// Then this could be drawn out to
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static bool IsValidIHasPerson<T>( this List<T>? list )
       where T : IHasPerson
    => (list is not null && list.Count > 0 && list[0].Person is not null);
}
```

Mind: I am not arguing the reasonability of just checking `list[0].Person`. If that's the requirement, so be it.

Usage example:

```
// Assuming PhoneInsured implements above mentioned IHasPerson
private bool IsValidPhoneInsured(List<PhoneInsured>? insured) => insured.IsValidIHasPersion();
```

EDIT: If you don't like extension methods, then this works as an ordinary static method, too.

Comment: You guys write code faster than I type - https://dotnetfiddle.net/MlUfb3 But I like examples with extension methods like this a lot!

Answer (score 2):

All your validation methods look the same, so you can have only one instead of 4.

First of all, create an interface `IValidAnnuitent` (or something like that, choose a proper naming for you). this interface should have only one property - `Person`:

```
public interface IValidAnnuitent
{
    Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Then all your classes (PhoneAnnuitant, AddressAnnuitant, Annuitant and PhoneInsured should implement this interface. For example:

```
public class PhoneAnnuitant : IValidAnnuitent
{
    Person Person { get; set; }
    // some other fields, properties and logic
}
```

Then just create a generic validation method where T should be IValidAnnuitent (so the compiler knows it has a `Person` property):

```
public bool IsValidList<T>(List<T>? items) where T : IValidAnnuitent
{
    return items is not null && items.Count > 0 && items[0].Person is not null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could create an interface something like IPeople with Person propety and then implement it in your classes.

```
public interface IPeople 
{
   Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Then your 4 classes would implement it. Then you could use simple generic method:

```
public IsValidPerson<TPeople>(List<IPeople?> peoples) where TPeople : IPeople
{
  if (peoples is not null && peoples.Any() && peoples.First().Person is not null)    
  // rest of your code 
}
```

Hint: When you use List, do not use Count() method - use .Count property instead. Count() method will iterate through collection to count records, .Count property returns the count instantly, because List is materialized collection and Count property is pre-calculated, Count() is Linq method and you risk unwanted iteration of the List.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generic method to return the value:

```
private bool IsValid<T>(List<T>? items) where T : IPerson
{
    if (items is not null && items.Count() > 0 && items[0].Person is not null) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use a generic method with type constraint, like `IsValidPersonList<T>()` below. Also you can consider article "How to Use Generics with Type Constraints to Handle Collections in C#", see: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2022/03/22/generics-type-constraints/

My take on this issue follows, also there's a working copy at - https://dotnetfiddle.net/MlUfb3

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Person {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}

interface IPersonValidation {
    public Person Person {get;set;}
}

class PhoneAnnuitant : IPersonValidation {
    public Person Person {get;set;}
}

class AddressAnnuitant : IPersonValidation {
    public Person Person {get;set;}
}

class Annuitant : IPersonValidation {
    public Person Person {get;set;}
}

class PhoneInsured : IPersonValidation {
    public Person Person {get;set;}
}


public class Validator
{
    private bool IsValidPhoneAnnuitent(List<PhoneAnnuitant> annuitants)
    {
        if (annuitants is not null && annuitants.Count() > 0 && annuitants[0].Person is not null) return true;
        return false;
    }

    private bool IsValidPersonList<T>(List<T> persons) where T: IPersonValidation
    {
        if (persons is not null && persons.Count() > 0 && persons[0].Person is not null) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Person client = new Person{FirstName = "Jonh", LastName = "Smith"};
        List<PhoneAnnuitant> phones = new List<PhoneAnnuitant>();
        phones.Add(new PhoneAnnuitant{Person = client});

        var addresses = new List<AddressAnnuitant>();
        addresses.Add(new AddressAnnuitant{Person = client});

        Console.WriteLine("Validation of List<PhoneAnnuitant> : " + new Validator().IsValidPhoneAnnuitent(phones));
        Console.WriteLine("Validation of List<AddressAnnuitant> : " + new Validator().IsValidPersonList(addresses));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is to much code and u should use Count instead of Count().

Comment: True, especially when List<T> is used. Just wanted to see how original code could benefit from generic method. I guess if List<T> was replaced by IEnumerable<T> then extension method Count() could be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I will post also my solution:

```
 private static bool IsValid<T>(List<T> lst, Func<string> personSelector) => (lst is not null && lst.Count > 0 && personSelector is not null);
```

and you can use it like this:

```
 var b1= IsValid<PhoneAnnuitant>(annuitantLst, () => annuitantLst[0].Person);
 var b2 = IsValid<AddressAnnuitant>(annuitantLst, () => annuitantLst[0].Person);
```

The advantage is that you don't need an extra interface for it and you can select also other fields instead of `Person`. So it is for a much general use. I used `string` as a type for the Person but can be any other type, you will just have to replace it inside the `Func`.